# LYNC 2010 lync control panel login problem

Tags: lync

I have installed Lync 2010 with no errors. When I try to open the Lync control panel, it asks  me for the username and password. I try to input Domain Administrator Credentials, but I can not login to the control panel. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you installed Lync did you add the CSAdministrator and RTCUniversalServerAdmins to your Administrator Member Of Security group?

Without CSAdministrator you cannot log into the Control Pannel, and without RTCUniversalServerAdmins, you will have some trouble in doing some advanced powershell stuff.

See: http://blog.schertz.name/2010/09/lync2010rc-deployment-part1/